# How to get log from an android application

Tags: android, logging, console

How to get log from an android application
I want to see the log files of an android app and all of its outputs when it runs. Please tell me how i can do this. Thanks in advance

Comment: You mean in your app or in your IDE?

Answer (score 0):

That's what **[LogCat](http://developer.android.com/tools/help/logcat.html)** is for. To enable Logcat go to Window-> Show View -> Other -> Android-> Logcat. It will show the debug and system logs.

Comment: He wants to get LogCat **inside application programatically**, not outside